# What are the best practices for sorting tables with sections?

Tags: tables, grid, sort, best-practice

When you have a table with sections, the sections denote a hierarchy for instance:

```
Name                             Corners                     Perimeter
- Standard Shapes                 7                          105
    Rectangle A                   4                           25
    Triangle B                    3                           23
    Circle C                      0                           57
+ Red Shapes                     34                          235
+ Blue Shapes                    24                          145
```

What would you expect the table header sort to do? Or what are some good design patterns to implement a sort also for the bottom level rows?

Comment: Could you add a column between "Name" and "Corners" to house the nested elements (Rectangle A, etc.)?

Comment: @Andy Yeah, the design/identification I know how to solve, what I'm wondering though, is how to so a secondary sort

Comment: I would expect the sorting to convert it to normal non-hierarchical table..

Answer (score 2):

I really liked an example from [this article](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/ultimate-guide-to-table-ui-patterns/) regarding table patterns:

[image]

I think the grey text of the cells that are clearly in the same row as the header/total helps to differentiate them from the actual sortable/expandable data. This example is missing controls for sorting, but I would assume arrows/chevrons/triangles/etc. would be in place beside the column labels.

Comment: I also like this example, but not sure how do you do a secondary sorting here. Meaning, if the user clicked on May - should it sorted the gray rows or the black inside the gray? We have a need to sort the black, but not sure how to make it clear that I'm sorting inside the sections

Comment: Yes, primary sorting would sort the unexpanded views. You could put the same sorting controls in the summary/total (grey) row for each expandable section.

Answer (score 1):

I guess sorting nested tables would sort each subset, not all of them combined together.

The same logic is used in table/grid grouping - sorting there sorts the items within each group, while there is another button that can reorder the groups based on the value of the field used for grouping - checkout [this example](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-grouping/grouping) for a live demo of that.

Answer (score 0):

Because your secondary sort is under Name, I would recommend that clicking on a subsection name (Standard Shapes) would toggle name sort a->z / z->a just for that section. This way you are only sorting on one data point (name) and in a single manner (alphabetical) even with 2 levels.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple more options

1. Consider a sort control that lives outside table headings
   [image]
2. Add additional options to each heading (menu); it will allow you to sort my more things than just one parameter
   [image]